# pixel length not same with size java bufferimage

Tags: java, image-processing, buffer, bufferedimage

i have 426px * 436px

but when i use byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

then i use system.out.printl(pixels.length) result is 557208 it is 3x 426x436
can someone explain it

Comment: 1 byte each for R, G, B. That makes 3 bytes per pixel (depending on the data type of the raster).

Comment: Note that if your image has alpha data, then you would need four bytes for each pixel, one for red, one for green, one for blue and one for the alpha. The BufferedImage API Type constants section will explain this to you.

Answer (score 1):

Each pixel requires 3 bytes, 1 for red, 1 for green, 1 for blue (assuming the image is using that color format, I would expect it to be that unless you changed the format).